# Displaying state content passed to a child component in React

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React (and web dev in general) trying to set up a simple app. 
I am sure this must be evident but could not find the solution for a day now..
With below code I get an error: *Uncaught Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {message}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.*

I also tried several ways to correct per other posts but never succeeded (and got different errors) and I feel I am missing here something very simple. Can someone look at my code and tell me what's wrong?

Parent component (a child of another component which passes id of the message that this one fetches from the server):

```
import React from 'react';
import Singlemessage from './Singlemessage';

class Viewmessage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isMessageLoaded: false,
      singleMessage: ''
    };
  }

componentDidMount () {
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/message'
    , {
      method: 'post',
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
      body: JSON.stringify({
        id: this.props.id,
      })
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {this.setState({isMessageLoaded: true, singleMessage : data})})
  }

  render () {      
    var { isMessageLoaded } = this.state
    if (!isMessageLoaded) {
        return <div>Loading...</div>
    }
      else {
        return (
            <Singlemessage message={this.state.singleMessage}/>
            )
        }
      }
    }

  export default Viewmessage
```

Singlemessage component:

```
import React from 'react';

const Singlemessage = ({ message }) => {
  return (

      <div>
       {message}
      </div>

  );
}

export default Singlemessage;
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently `data` is an object, not a string.

`.then(data => {this.setState({isMessageLoaded: true, singleMessage : data})})`

Make sure that what you are actually passing to `singleMessage` in `setState` function is a string.

At this moment, probably an object is passed to the child component, which cannot be rendered.

I'd suggest you to check out what's passed as `message` in the child component:

```
console.log(message);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.then(data => {this.setState({isMessageLoaded: true, singleMessage : data})})
```

Here you are setting `this.state.singleMessage` to refer to `data`, which apparently is an object. Either, you need to get a string from that object when you set state, or you need to render the object as a string in your child component, perhaps by getting one of the keys from `message`.

Comment: Thanks! In the Singlemessage component with message.map(message => (<div key={message.id}> then display the message as {message.message} works. For a different solution, can you help me with how to get a string from that object? I checked from other posts I could use JSON.stringify or a Javascript function but I am not sure how to apply this at setState.

Comment: @dbogyi You could do `.then(data => {this.setState({isMessageLoaded: true, singleMessage : data.message})})`. Then you can leave the original `render()` method as it is.